# How to change "year.month" format into "Year-Month" format in R

Tags: r, date, reformatting

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Month           GSI
1993.01     -0.57567056
1993.02     -1.15549239
1993.03     -1.00353071
1993.04     -0.10698880
1993.05     -0.31903591
1993.06      0.30361638
1993.07      1.24528915
1993.08      0.85104370
1993.09      1.24680092
1993.10      1.42521406
```

As you can see, the "Month" column is meant to be a date in the format "year.month". I would like to reformat this column to the traditional "%Y-%m" format so that the data frame looks something more like this:

```
  Date          GSI
1993-01     -0.57567056
1993-02     -1.15549239
1993-03     -1.00353071
1993-04     -0.10698880
1993-05     -0.31903591
1993-06      0.30361638
1993-07      1.24528915
1993-08      0.85104370
1993-09      1.24680092
1993-10      1.42521406
```

How can I go about changing the format of this column to be recognizable as a date column? Currently, the class of the "Month" column is numeric.

Comment: Or even - `df$Month <- sub('.', '-', fixed = TRUE, df$Month)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sub`, with capturing groups in the regular expression:

```r
df$Month <- sub("^(\\d{4})\\.(\\d{2})$", "\\1-\\2", format(df$Month, 2))

df
#>      Month        GSI
#> 1  1993-01 -0.5756706
#> 2  1993-02 -1.1554924
#> 3  1993-03 -1.0035307
#> 4  1993-04 -0.1069888
#> 5  1993-05 -0.3190359
#> 6  1993-06  0.3036164
#> 7  1993-07  1.2452892
#> 8  1993-08  0.8510437
#> 9  1993-09  1.2468009
#> 10 1993-10  1.4252141
```

---

**Input Data**

```r
df <- structure(list(Month = c(1993.01, 1993.02, 1993.03, 1993.04, 
1993.05, 1993.06, 1993.07, 1993.08, 1993.09, 1993.1), GSI = c(-0.57567056, 
-1.15549239, -1.00353071, -0.1069888, -0.31903591, 0.30361638, 
1.24528915, 0.8510437, 1.24680092, 1.42521406)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

df
#>      Month        GSI
#> 1  1993.01 -0.5756706
#> 2  1993.02 -1.1554924
#> 3  1993.03 -1.0035307
#> 4  1993.04 -0.1069888
#> 5  1993.05 -0.3190359
#> 6  1993.06  0.3036164
#> 7  1993.07  1.2452892
#> 8  1993.08  0.8510437
#> 9  1993.09  1.2468009
#> 10 1993.10  1.4252141
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `lubridate` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df <- mutate(df, date = ym(Month))

# if you don't know dplyr, use:
df$date <- ym(df$Month)
```

Note that this solution also coerces the result into a POSIXct (date) formatted variable. Transmute mutates and deletes and the month variable.

`lubridate` is the gold standard package for working with date (and time) data in R. Find the cheatsheat [here](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/blob/master/lubridate.pdf).